Running ros1 packages with ros2 data
I'm trying to run different lidar based SLAM methods in order to produce a map of an environment. I've recorded my data in both .db3 and .mcap formats, but a lot of SLAM methods (an example being Interactive SLAM by SMRT-AIST) are only implemented on ROS1 with the .bag format. Is there any way to either change the modern formats to .bag or is there another way to use these older packages with ROS2 datatypes?

As discussed in this link: https://answers.ros.org/question/352466/converting-ros2-bag-to-ros1-bag/ it seems that you can use ternaris/rosbags to convert ROS2 bag to ROS1. You can also take a look in this discussion. https://answers.ros.org/question/388484/how-to-read-ros2-bag-file-in-ros1/
In case of slam method for ROS2 with 3D lidar, LIO-slam have support for ROS2. There is another option like using ROSbridge which I'm not sure about the changes in data rate but you can look into.
